# AngularJS Single Source Of Truth In Service/Factory For Multiple DIrectives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The Goal**

What I'm trying to achieve is using a service* to hold the single source of truth for my directives. I realize that I can use API calls, but the problem with that is that the app I'm working with is slow enough (I'd change that if I could) it doesn't need extra calls. Plus, that wouldn't keep changes synced as changes are made to the data throughout the app unless I saved the data with every single change. I would like to do something like this from controllers and other services:

```
function SomeController(['DataService', function() {
    var dataToCollectWithoutAPICall = DataService.currentData;
}]);

function SomeService(['DataService', function() {
    var dataToCollectWithoutAPICall = DataService.currentData;
}]);
```

That way when a service or controller updates the `currentData` it updates for the others as well.

**EDIT:**
Should have said 'updates the controllers/services within that instance of a directive'. So updates to `<directive id="first"/>` shouldn't update the data for `<directive id="second">`. However any changes to data for `<directive id="first"/>` should update the data for all controllers/services within `<directive id="first"/>` only;

**The Problem**

This works great if you only have one element using that directive, however if you have a second element then one directive can update the service and the other directive's data is updated as well.

From first directive:

`DataService.currentData = 'First Data';`

Then second directive updates this:

`DataService.currentData = 'Second Data';`

All of a sudden the first directives `dataToCollectWithoutAPICall` is 'Second Data'.

I'm avoiding putting the data on $scope because services can't use the $scope and then the service is no longer the single source of truth.

**The Questions**

1. Is it possible to isolate the data for each directive?
2. Is there a unique identifier for each directive in Angular that controllers/services know about?
3. Does anyone know a way around this?

One idea I would be willing to use is creating a unique identifier for each directive, e.g. `DataService.currentData['UniqueIdentifier']`.

I've also considered using local storage, but the browsers that I have to support don't all use local storage and I would run into the same problem of one directive overriding another's.

I'm willing to completely re-think the way I'm going about this. I just want a SSoT that all controllers/services can pull data from.

* I'm using `services` to mean either services or factories.

Comment: Your goal is _"That way when a service or controller updates the currentData it updates for the others as well"_. In the next paragraph, however, you describe that as a problem. I'm confused.

Comment: @zeroflagL I edited the question. You're right, it wasn't quite clear what I was meaning in the goals. That's what happens when you think others can read your mind :)